# Android Development: set a program as default

Tags: android

How do i make my program load as default example for a url link?

Thank you!

PS* sorry for last missunderstanding Question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost entirely certain that the user has to set it, for security reasons. For example, if you have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is listening for `intent.foo`, but there are other receivers in other apps that are also listening for the same intent, the user will be presented with a dialog which lets them select what app they want to work on the intent, and whether or not to set it as default.

Comment: yes the user will have a choose to set mine or the stock program.